# SearhEntry operation in LDAP wso2 esb

Tags: search, ldap, wso2, esb

I am trying to use searchEntry operation in LDAP in wso2 esb to search for a particular emailid. How I will create request payload for this? Could you Please give one sample example for this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by setting below  parameters for anonymous connection to ldap.

```
"securityPrincipal":"",
   "securityCredentials":"",
   "secureConnection":"true",
   "disableSSLCertificateChecking":"true",
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with following sample proxy for the above operation (searchEntry) :
Here we have build the request payload for the searchEntry operation inside the proxy using payload factory mediator.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="ldap_search_payload"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="https,http">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>
            {
              "providerUrl": "ldap://XYZ.example.com:389/",
              "securityPrincipal": "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com",
              "securityCredentials": "password",
              "secureConnection": "",
              "disableSSLCertificateChecking": "false",
             "dn": "ou=People,dc=example,dc=com",
             "objectClass": "inetOrgPerson",
             "attributes": "uid",
             "filters": {
                "mail": "testDim2@wso2.com"
              },
            "onlyOneReference": "false"
 }
       </format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property expression="json-eval($.objectClass)" name="objectClass"/>
         <property expression="json-eval($.dn)" name="dn"/>
         <property expression="json-eval($.attributes)" name="attributes"/>
         <property expression="json-eval($.onlyOneReference)" name="onlyOneReference"/>
         <property expression="json-eval($.providerUrl)" name="providerUrl"/>
         <property expression="json-eval($.securityPrincipal)" name="securityPrincipal"/>
         <property expression="json-eval($.securityCredentials)"
                   name="securityCredentials"/>
         <property expression="json-eval($.filters)" name="filters"/>
         <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>
         <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>
         <ldap.init>
            <providerUrl>{$ctx:providerUrl}</providerUrl>
            <securityPrincipal>{$ctx:securityPrincipal}</securityPrincipal>
            <securityCredentials>{$ctx:securityCredentials}</securityCredentials>
            <secureConnection>{$ctx:secureConnection}</secureConnection>
            <disableSSLCertificateChecking>{$ctx:disableSSLCertificateChecking}</disableSSLCertificateChecking>
         </ldap.init>
         <ldap.searchEntry>
            <objectClass>{get-property('objectClass')}</objectClass>
            <dn>{get-property('dn')}</dn>
            <attributes>{get-property('attributes')}</attributes>
            <filters>{get-property('filters')}</filters>
            <onlyOneReference>{get-property('onlyOneReference')}</onlyOneReference>
         </ldap.searchEntry>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <faultSequence>
         <respond/>
      </faultSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Please find the response while invoking the above proxy

```
{
    "result": {
        "entry": [
            {
                "dn": "uid=john_002,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com",
                "uid": "john_002"
            },
            {
                "dn": "uid=john_003,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com",
                "uid": "john_003"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In this sample, I got the relevant search entries which have the email id "testDim2@wso2.com" with the "uid" attributes of that email id user's in the response.

Comment: Hi Priya,Thanks for the response. I am using the same code only but I don't have ldap admin userid and password, so i am not passing  any userid & password. Also for disableSSLCertificateChecking Iam passing true since it is 389 port which runs on without SSL. After doing this I am getting error "simple bind failed: ldap.xx.com:389".. Please help...

Comment: Can you try with "disableSSLCertificateChecking":"false", since this value indicates "The boolean value to check whether certificate enables or not".  You need to give a password for "securityCredentials".

Comment: Thanks Vivekananthan for the answer but since the SSL is not enabled, so i am using true for disableSSLCertificateChecking and I need to do anonymous login in ldap server. So, Please tell me how i can have anonymous access or login into ldap server. Thanks in advance.